# How to uninstall ubuntu 12.10

Tags: uninstall, live-usb, windows-xp

I need to uninstall ubuntu but i cant find how to for my situation. I have ubuntu and windows xp both installed on my computer. However, the windows xp came preinstalled so i dont have the cd. I do not have a dvd/cd drive on my computer (I installed ubuntu via usb). Is there any way i could uninstall ubuntu while keeping xp installed.

Answer (score 1):

...I messed around with Ubuntu on a Windows Laptop, tried to dual boot them, but Ubuntu would not actually load. Since it was out of warranty for quite a while and also did not have a genuine Windows CD/DVD at hand I kind of forced the deletion of Ubuntu. I ran a Ubuntu live session from a DVD. I think lately the live session comes with GParted preinstalled. I ran GParted, deleted all the Ubuntu related partitions and then made them into a single NTFS free space partition. Because of deleting vital information for Booting I ran Boot-Repair. After finishing those I managed to boot into Windows with no problems and free of Ubuntu. Indeed the first screen shown scared me a little as it was a black screen with maybe 2 or 3 lines of text, but the booting sequence afterwards proceeded as usual.

I actually gambled doing so and risked trashing the laptop (from the OS point of view) because I did not know whether it was going to work or not... but it worked, even if it was only a lucky shot. I do recommend looking up some more info, internet is the best documentation source (couple of video tutorials, other forums and opinions)

I'll give you the what you need in order to install GParted (if missing from the live session) and for Boot-Repair, as well as the sources where I got them from.

PLEASE! If a more experienced user takes a look over this brief me in if my approach was "morally" fine or I just trashed something [-o<

GParted

> To install Gparted in Ubuntu Linux enter the following in the terminal. You will be prompted for your password

sudo apt-get install gparted

> Once the Gparted package has been installed, launch it via the terminal by using the following command. You will be prompted for your password. (you have to run it as super-user)

sudo gparted

> source http://www.techheadz.co.uk/223.html#.UwAI6lSki0w

Boot-Repair

install Boot-Repair in Ubuntu
- boot your computer on a Ubuntu live-CD or live-USB.

- choose "Try Ubuntu"
- connect internet
- open a new Terminal, then type:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update

- Press Enter.
- Then type:

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)

- Press Enter

  -Please do follow the using instructions from the source:
      https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Praise the Community for the awesome open source concept, it makes life easier by sharing information good to test on your machine, trash it, fix it and make it better... It's kind of fun actually ^_^ ...until you lose data you care for :| 
Take care!